# Namespace in HBase?

Tags: hbase

How can I `list down` all the tables created under a single namespace in HBase? 
In Hbase, is there anything like `show tables;` which we can use in Hive  to find all tables under a particular database.

Comment: In HBase you can use `list` command to show tables, but I'm not sure about how to use that on Hive.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use commands `list_namespace_tables` from HBase shell.  It lists all tables that are members of the namespace.
Example

```
hbaseshell> list_namespace_tables 'default'
```

You can list the namespaces like so:

```
hbaseshell> list_namespace
NAMESPACE
default
hbase
```