# How to check whether Namespace already exists in Hbase or not?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I want to check weather Namespace already exists in Hbase or not , how can I get this ?

Comment: pls see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129079/namespace-in-hbase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the namespace whether it is available by

`hbase> list_namespace`

You can find all the namespace commands in the [Hbase Shell Commands](http://hadooptutorial.info/hbase-shell-commands-in-practice/#NamespaceCommands)

Answer (score 0):

From shell you can use:

```
echo 'list_namespace' | hbase shell 2>/dev/null | grep 'ns_to_search'
echo $?
```